# Minimizing the sum of 3 variables subject to equality and integrality constraints

Tags: python, algorithm, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am working on a programming (using Python) problem where I have to solve the following type of linear equation in 3 variables:

x, y, z are all integers.

Equation example:  `2x + 5y + 8z = 14`

Condition: `Minimize x + y + z`

I have been trying to search for an algorithm for finding a solution to this, in an optimum way. If anybody has any idea please guide me through algorithm or code-sources.

I am just curious, what can be done if this problem is extrapolated to n variables?

I don't want to use hit & trial loops to keep checking for values. Also, there may be a scenario that equation has no solution.

**UPDATE**

Adding lower bounds condition:

```
x, y, z >= 0
x, y, z are natural
```

Comment: As has been pointed out in the answer below that problem is unbounded unless you have bounds on your variables `x, y, z`. It is common in some problems to have a lower bound of zero for all variables, but you have not specified this. In general for linear programming problems in Python I would recommend [PuLP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PuLP).

Comment: Maybe it sounds non-sense, does (x,y,z) needed to be an integer solution?

Comment: Yes, looking for integral solutions only.

Comment: I added Update2 above for what I found while finding a programming approach to algorithm. All the links which helped are shared, thanks all for helping out!

Answer (score 3):

Any triple *(x, y, z)*, with *z = (14 - 2x - 5y) / 8*, satisfies your constraint.

Note that *x + y + (14 - 2x - 5y) / 8* is unbounded from below. This function decreases when each of *x* and *y* decrease, with no finite minimum.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the best mathematical solution. But, I was actually looking to solve this problem programmatically. I found `coin-change algorithm` which I can use with such kinds of problems I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You have an equality-constrained **integer program** (IP) in just 3 dimensions. The equality constraint `2 x + 5 y + 8 z = 14` defines a plane in 3-dimensional space. Parametrizing it,

```
x = 7 - 2.5 u - 4 v
y = u
z = v
```

we obtain an *unconstrained* IP in 2 dimensions. Given the integrality constraints, we have `u <- {0,2}` and `v <- {0,1}`. Enumerating all **four** `(u,v)` pairs, we conclude that the minimum is `4` and that it is attained at `(u,v) = (2,0)` and `(u,v) = (0,1)`, which correspond to `(x,y,z) = (2,2,0)` and `(x,y,z) = (3,0,1)`, respectively.

Using [PuLP](http://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/) to solve the integer program:

```
from pulp import *

# decision variables
x = LpVariable("x", 0, None, LpInteger)
y = LpVariable("y", 0, None, LpInteger)
z = LpVariable("z", 0, None, LpInteger)

# define integer program (IP)
prob = LpProblem("problem", LpMinimize)
prob += x+y+z                   # objective function
prob += 2*x + 5*y + 8*z == 14   # equality constraint

# solve IP
prob.solve()

# print results
print LpStatus[prob.status]
print value(x)
print value(y)
print value(z)
```

which produces `x = 3`, `y = 0` and `z = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Another tool to solve this type of problems is [SCIP](http://scip.zib.de). There is also an easy to use Python interface available on GitHub: [PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt).

In general (mixed) integer programming problems are very hard to solve (NP complexity) and often even simple looking instances with only a few variables and constraints can take hours to prove the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

From your first equation:

x = (14 - 5y - 8x) / 2

so, you now only need to minimize

(14 - 5y - 8z) / 2 + y + z

which is

(14 - 3y - 6z) / 2

But we can ignore the ' / 2' part for minimization purposes.

Presumably, there must be some other constraints on your problem, since as described the solution is that both y and z may grow without bound.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any general fast solution for n variables, or not using hit & trail loops. But for the given specific equation  `2x + 5y + 8z = 14`, there maybe some shortcut based on observation.

Notice that the range is very small for any possible solutions:

`0<=x<=7`,  `0<=y<=2`,  `0<=z<=1`

Also other than x = 7, you have at least to use 2 variables.
**(x+y+z = 7 for this case)**

---

Let's find what we got if using only 2 variables:

If you choose to use (x,z) or (y,z), as `z` can only be 1, `x` or `y` is trivial.

**(x+y+z = 4 for (x,z),  no solution for (y,z))**

If you choose to use (x,y), as `x`'s coefficient is even and `y`'s coefficient is odd,  you must choose even number of `y` to achieve an even R.H.S. (14). Which means `y` must be 2, `x` is then trivial.

**(x+y+z = 4 for this case)**

---

Let's find what we got if using all 3 variables:

Similarly, `z` must be 1, so basically it's using 2 variables (x,y) to achieve 14-8 = 6 which is even.

Again we use similar argument, so we must choose even number of `y` which is 2, however at this point 2y + 1z > 14 already, which means there is **no solution using all 3 variables**.

---

Therefore simply by logic, reduce the equation by using 1 or 2 variables, we can find that **minimum x+y+z is 4** to achieve 14 **(x=3,y=0,z=1  or x=2,y=2,z=0)**