# Solving integer programs in Python with PuLP

Tags: python, julia, integer-programming

I am working on a Python package for computing several NP-Hard graph invariants. The current version of the package uses brute force for nearly all of the algorithms, but I am very interested in using integer programming to help speed up the computations for larger graphs.

For example, a simple integer program for solving the independence number of an n-vertex graph is to maximize [image: formula] given the constraints [image: formula], where [image: formula].

How do I solve this using PuLP? Is PuLP my best option, or would it be beneficial to use solvers in another language, like Julia, and interface may package with those?

Comment: i.e. you are looking for the python equivalent of JuMP.jl

Comment: Here's an example of how PuLP works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39886268/6338725

Comment: This is quite broad as currently stated. Could you focus on a specific problem and narrow this down somewhat?

Answer (score 0):

I don't propose to write your full implementation for you, but to address the final question about PuLP versus other languages.

PuLP provides a Python wrapper over a range of existing LP Solvers.

Once you have specified your problem with a Python syntax, it converts it to another language internally (e.g. you can save `.lp` files, and inspect them) and passes that to any one of a number of third-party solvers, that generally aren't written in Python.

So there is no need to learn another language to get a better solver.